# Execute PHP files periodicaly

Tags: php, scripting, cron

The question is very easy, I want to execute several php files every "N" minutes. For example:

every N minutes
{
    execute(script1.php) 
    execute(script2.php)
    execute(script3.php)
}

I know about crontab but i was trying to find another solution. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: crontab is the best solution. There is no threading in PHP there for you can't start a thread and say just run this every N seconds. What's wrong with crontab?

Comment: another vote for cron, if you can't use it for some reason, there are other commercial automation solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a Cron job is the usual solution. Can you explain why you don't want to use CRON? I've also seen libraries that add cron-like features to your system. For example in the Java/Groovy/Grails world there's the Quartz library/plugin. A quick Google search yielded a PHP library called phpJobScheduler that seems similar to Quartz. I have never used phpJobScheduler so I can't vouch for it.

I'd be interested in why you don't want to use crontabs for this? Are you going to be the primary web operations person running this server or will you be relying on an existing sysop team? You may want to get their input since they are the ones who will be most impacted by what method you choose. I've found they tend to be fond of cron for simple scheduling.

Comment: Managing a several cron jobs using the standard interface (or via many control panels) can become an admin nightmare.

Its far easier to install:
http://phpjobscheduler.co.uk/ then you can easily see and edit pages of tasks in seconds (but I would say that as it is my Open source app).

Answer (score 0):

On windows I used built-in proggie called Task Scheduler. As for linux, yes, cron jobs is your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a php script to loop forever do X every N minutes and run the command with a & to make it a background process.

/path/to/php /home/user/bgscript.php &

If you want it to always run, you'd then have to add it to startup init.d or services depending on flavor of *nix.

This solution is possible but personally I would highly recommend going with crontab, its established, proven and works well! Why are you avoiding it?

Comment: The main reason for avoiding crontab is that I don't now anything about it and I was just finding easier in PHP. 
Anyway, thank you very much for answering, I'll try to use crontab.
BTW, is possible to use crontab in you hosting server or it depends on your hosting company?

Comment: That's going to depend on your host and your hosting package, they all have different levels of access that they give you to your server.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a script and let it run as a daemon and perform certain tasks on a set interval, but that's actually just simulating cron ... and if you have the ability to run a php script as a daemon you should really also be able to run it as a cronjob since that's what crons are made for.

If you need more info on how to run a php script as a daemon [read this great intro](http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/create_daemons_in_php/). There is also a great comparison between daemon and cron inthere, worth the read.